# Issue with socket.io and domain name

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I get an issue using `socket.io`.

My code : `var socket = io.connect('SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.fr');`

Response error :

> WebSocket connection to
>   `ws://SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.fr/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=u2V-6uOMZrBtnCK5AAAH`
>   failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code:
>   503

My `SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.fr` is a type A domain.

Comment: It seems that your server is giving an *unavailable* error. It doesn't seem to be a problem on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

What this actually means is that the environment hosting your `socket.io` service is not `WebSocket` enabled.

When `socket.io` first establishes a connection it will use `long-polling`, once connected, it then attempts to ***upgrade*** the connection to using `WebSocket`. If your hosting environment doesn't support `WebSocket` then you will see this message. It doesn't prevent `socket.io` from working it simply means it attempted to upgrade to `WebSocket` as the transport but failed. Now, if you explicitly state that `socket.io` should only use `WebSocket`, then your connection will not work.

An example would be IIS 7.5 or below. [`WebSocket` isn't supported in IIS until version 8.0](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-websocket-protocol-support), so anyone using `socket.io` in an IIS 7.5 or below environment would see this message every time a connection is established.

This is discussed in the [Engine.io Goals](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io#goals) & [Engine.io Architecture](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io#architecture).

[Engine.io](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io) is what socket.io is built on top of.